# Erro de associação Has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Erro : Undefined method 'address' for #Contact:código de memória do objeto

Estou fazendo um teste em Rails. Quero consultar um dado da tabela address de um objeto instanciado de contact: contact has_one address.

Estou usando o Rails Console e executando o código abaixo:

```
contato = Contact.first
contato.address.street
```

E recebo o erro.

No model de contact tem uma associação da seguinte forma:

```
has_one :address
```

OBS: Na migrate de address existe uma referência a contact.

Comment: O seu modelo Address tem um belongs_to :contact ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **has_one:**

- Deve ser utilizado quando o seu modelo "tem" outro modelo.

Quando dizemos "tem" estamos nos referindo a:

*Contact*

*Adress*
 - contact_id

Nesse caso, todo contato (*Contact*) tem um endereço (*Adress*): "Contact has_one address".

### **belongs_to**:

- Deve ser utilizado quando seu modelo "pertence a" outro modelo

*Contact*
 - address_id

*Adress*

Nesse caso, todo contato (*Contact*) pertence a um endereço (*Address*): "Contact belongs_to address"

> Essa confusão é natural, dado que na maioria das vezes costumamos pensar no "tem" como "tem o id" ou "tem a referência". Mas o que vale é justamente o sentido puro da sentença, pense que o endereço em si (*Address*) não "é do contato" (*Contact*). O endereço existe sem a necessidade do contato existir. O contato "pertence ao endereço" assim como outros contatos podem pertencer a esse mesmo endereço.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que seus relationships estão um pouco bagunçados. Dê uma olhada na [documentação](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).

No seu caso, ao invés de usar o `has_one`, use um `belongs_to`.

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :contact

end
```

Comment: belongs_to já está sendo usado, mas por questões de teste eu queria fazer o caminho inverso, que é o has_one...